# Calculate the average value in certain time interval and summarize the calculated values in a new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a timerseries dataframe in Python. The time value represents the index. The time value repeats every 0.1 seconds.

Pandas dataframe:

| Timestamp | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.000000 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.100000 | 2 | 4 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.200000 | 3 | 6 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.300000 | 4 | 8 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.400000 | 5 | 10 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.500000 | 6 | 12 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.600000 | 7 | 14 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.700000 | 8 | 16 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.800000 | 9 | 18 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.900000 | 10 | 20 |

...

Now I want to create a new dataframe from the existing one. The time span is now 0.5seconds. 5 values from the above dataframe are to be combined and the average value is to be formed.

New Dataframe with mean function:

| Timestamp | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.000000 | 3 | 6 |
| 2023-06-16 13:38:38.500000 | 8 | 16 |

How can I solve this problem. Is there an easy way to implement it with pandas here?
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create new column for your needed time intervals:

```
df['ds'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Timestamp']).floor('.5S')
```

then `groupby` it

```
df.groupby(['ds']).mean()
```